# What should I use as training data for base (level 1) classifiers in ensembling?

Tags: ensemble-modeling, ensemble

Can I just take all training data that I have, train the base models on them and then take their results and use them for training level 2 model? Is this a good practice, or should it be done differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, but your model will not generalize well. You should not use base-model predictions from data, which were used to fit the base model.
Thus, you have to get the base model predictions for the training data using cross-validation. This is called "model stacking".

[This page](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/comprehensive-guide-for-ensemble-models/) has a good explanation:

1. Split your training data into subsets, predict the target for each subset using all other subsets.

[image]

2. Fit the base model on the whole training data and predict the target for the test set.

[image]

3. Do this for multiple base models. Now you have train and test set predictions for each base model. In this example we have two base models:
   [image]
4. Fit an ensemble model on the base training predictions and evaluate the performance on the base test predictions.